# Charge density within a PIN diode

Tags: electric-fields, semiconductor-physics, charge-carrier

Consider the following problem regarding the p-type -intrinsic - n-type (PIN) diode from the Semiconductor Devices fundementals text book:

[image]

[image]

According to the solution manual the charge density is given by the following plot:

[image]

What I don't understand is how is the charge density within the intrinsic region equal to 0? Due to high hole concentration in p-region compared to intrinsic region  ,holes will diffuse to the intrinsic region near $\frac{x_i }{2}$ so in intrinsic region there should be excess hole concentration near $\frac{x_i }{2}$ so the charge density should be positive near $\frac{x_i }{2}$ within the intrinsic region . Likewise, electrons will diffuse from n-type region into intrinsic region, creating excess electron concentration near $\frac{-x_i }{2}$ so the charge density should be negative near $\frac{-x_i }{2}$ within the intrinsic regions.

Or is the plot in solution manual supposed to be given under assumptions like steady state conditions where all excess holes and electrons in intrinsic region recombine or by using the depletion region approximation?

Comment: The question might not be well worded, but based on the given answer they're asking about the fixed charge left behind in the depletion region, not the charge of the free carriers. The i region has very low fixed charge because it has very low dopant concentration.

Comment: @ThePhoton well for the second part of the question , plotting the electric field according to the solution manual the electric field is constant in intrinsic reigon so by poisson equation the charge density within the intrinsic reigon is zero so there are no excess mobile charges within intrinsic reigon which can't be the case . So is an assumption made to give this answer like steady state or depleation reigon approximation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depletion region covers the entire i region as well as part of the p region and part of the n region. It's called the depletion region because it is depleted of mobile carriers. You should not expect excess mobile carriers there.

In the p and n parts of the depletion region the mobile carrier density is much less than the fixed charges from the acceptors/donors, so those dominate the $\rho(x)$ graph. In the i region we also neglect any contribution from mobile charge (and from the very low acceptor or donor density) and take the charge density as 0.

Of course when the diode is forward biased there will be a non-zero mobile charge density in the depletion region. However these carriers are quickly swept out of the depletion region by the electric field, and deposited into the p or n region, where they build up and must migrate by diffusion to the device contacts.

The mobile charge carrier density in the depletion region is in any case small enough that we neglect it in these kind of exercises.

> I don't understand is how is the charge density within the intrinsic region equal to 0?

The fixed charge density is very low (approximately 0) because this is an intrinsic region with very low acceptor and donor concentration.

The mobile charge density is low because this is part of the depletion region where mobile charge is swept away by the electric field.

So the net charge density is approximately 0 because there is very low fixed charge density and very low mobile charge density.

> holes will diffuse to the intrinsic region near $\frac{x_i }{2}$ so in intrinsic region there should be excess hole concentration near $\frac{x_i }{2}$ so the charge density should be positive near $\frac{x_i }{2}$ within the intrinsic region .

In the $\rho(x)$ graph you can see there is a positive charge region to the right of the i region and a negative charge region to the left of the i region. Therefore there will be E field from right to left and any mobile carriers that do reach the i region (by diffusion or any other way (for example photoexcitation)) will be swept away.